# Generate user ids in a sequence using sqlalchemy in sqllite databse.

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I need to give Guest users ids ie,guest1,guest2... How can I make sqllite generate such ids using sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign an id like this:

```
class Guest(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    guest_id = db.Column(db.String(15))
```

the database will automatically assign an autoincrementing integer as the id.

UPDATE: The id will only be set after the object has been committed to the DB so to achieve what you want to do you will need to call a method on the object after it has been committed.

```
def create_guest(self):
    db.session.add(self)
    db.session.commit()
    self.guest_id = 'guest{}'.format(self.id)
```

Comment: I need a string before that auto generated integer.

Comment: Do you actually need the string or could you override the `__repr__` method to display any instances of the class?

Comment: I think it would be better practice to use an integer id and create another column that will be the string `guest` plus the id.